# Removing MySQL 5.7 Completely

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to uninstall mysql from my ubuntu 12.04 completely. But not able to.

I tried a lot of commands. But nothing is working. Can anyone help out here!

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I am not able to understand what to do.
I want to remove everything regarding MySQL. Whenever I am trying to locate it. I am getting that.

I want everything to be removed. mysql-server, mysql-client, mysql-libraries and even configuration.

Please help me!!!

Comment: Is the removal successful?
if yes try `sudo apt-get autoclean`. It'll remove the useless packages

Comment: what is left that you are trying to remove? Have you tried apt-get purge or dpkg --purge?

Comment: Are you trying to run `locate mysql`? If yes, then try running `updatedb` before running `locate`.

Comment: An advice : ask [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: Yes I tried. But still there are a lot of things are remaining related to MySQL

Comment: Guys when I am running the command "locate mysql"
I still get a no. of directories where mysql is remaining even after purge remove :(

Comment: can you list what remains?  Are they database directories or mysql config/logs.

Comment: I recommend this question for re-opening.  This is a task that must often performed by programmers.

Answer (score 372):

First of all, do a backup of your needed databases with `mysqldump`

> Note: If you want to restore later, just backup your relevant databases, and not the WHOLE, because the whole database might actually be the reason you need to purge and reinstall).

**In total, do this:**

```sh
sudo service mysql stop  #or mysqld
sudo killall -9 mysql
sudo killall -9 mysqld
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deluser -f mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.7
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

**All above commands in single line (just copy and paste)**:

```sh
sudo service mysql stop && sudo killall -9 mysql && sudo killall -9 mysqld && sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo deluser mysql && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.7 && sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.7 && sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql && sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Comment: Before all of this you have to stop the mysql service.

"sudo service stop".

Otherwise you will get error like "userdel: user mysql is currently logged in".

Comment: What about also deleting the user group?

Comment: It worked great with tasksel. i couldn't make another password with just removing/adding lamp

Comment: For an even more **complete** uninstall, I would also include the removal of configuration and logs: 

`sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql`
and 
`sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql`

Comment: Confirmed that this also works to remove **MySQL 5.6** (just change the version number in the relevant commands in this answer).

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with MySQL 5.5

Comment: Also worked for MariaDB.  I had conflicts after installing/removing both, and clearing all MySQL/MariaDB fixed it. (btw, needs to replace `mysql` with `mariadb` in commands)

Comment: I had to remove packages listed by `dpkg -l | grep mysql` to completely remove mysql

Comment: I found ```sudo deluser mysql``` would report that the user was in use by a process id. You can use ```sudo deluser -f mysql``` to force the user delete in this case, or kill the process with ```kill -p pid``` and then do ```sudo deluser mysql```

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep mysql`, then `dpkg -r mysql-server-8.0` or `dpkg -P mysql-server-8.0` finally did it at the end.

Answer (score 80):

You need to remove the /var/lib/mysql folder. Also, purge when you remove the packages (I'm told this helps).

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`

I was encountering similar issues. The second line got rid of my issues and allowed me to set up MySql from scratch. Hopefully it helps you too!

Comment: Following code helped me.
`sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/mysql`

Answer (score 29):

Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Run these commands separately as each command requires confirmation & if run as a block, the command below the one currently running will cancel the confirmation (leading to the command not being run).

Please refer to [How do I uninstall Mysql?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql)

Comment: In my case, 1st and 2nd answer need to follow.