# I can't unistall mysql on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I unistalled mysql-server from my ubuntu 12.10 machine, but if I type "mysql" on shell it prompts me the command line of a possible another mysql instance.

I want to remove it completely.
I tried this command: sudo apt-get remove mysql-server php5-mysql  and
                      sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client mysql-server

They run ok like it was unistalled everything about mysql.But as I said, if I type mysql on shell it prompts me mysql command line.

Please, I need help.

Comment: Please refer to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Run remove --purge on all the packages including common as shown above, and then remove the /var/lib/mysql folder.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have mysql fully installed on a system, it includes both the server (mysqld) and the client (/usr/local/bin/mysql or similar).

Therefore you have to remove the client as well as the server in order to get rid of what runs when you type 'mysql' on the command line.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client
```