# MySQL can't write to temp directory

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I tried everything and whenever i try to start `mysql` i get this error

```
140526 18:21:36 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/mysql/ibAlmthH' (Errcode: 13)
```

I even tried to chnage `tmp` dir in `my.cnf` with full write permissions but i still get that error

I tried this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16178696

But still same error

what should i do

Comment: May be permission issue for that directory, Have you check it?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan its not permission issue, its already 777

Comment: errno `EPIPE` is 13 for "Broken pipe"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch errno 13 is 'Permission denied' defined in `asm-generic/errno-base.h` (CentOS 5.3) `#define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this, from the stackoverflow question number-2783313 may it help:

Recent Ubuntu Server Editions (such as 10.04) ship with AppArmor and MySQL's profile might be in enforcing mode by default. You can check this by executing `sudo aa-status` like so:

```
# sudo aa-status
5 profiles are loaded.
5 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /sbin/dhclient3
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
0 profiles are in complain mode.
1 processes have profiles defined.
1 processes are in enforce mode :
   /usr/sbin/mysqld (1089)
0 processes are in complain mode.
```

If mysqld is included in enforce mode, then it is the one probably denying the write. Entries would also be written in /var/log/messages when AppArmor blocks the writes/accesses. What you can do is edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and add `/data/` and `/data/*` near the bottom like so:

```
...
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
    ...
    /var/log/mysql/ r,
    /var/log/mysql/* rw,
    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid w,
    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
    /data/ r,
    /data/* rw,
}
```

And then make AppArmor reload the profiles.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

**WARNING**: the change above will allow MySQL to read and write to the /data directory. We hope you've already considered the security implications of this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command manually:

```
touch /mysql/ibAlmthH
```

If it failed to create it, you then have a filesystem problem, e.g. read-only filesystem,
So you need to fix the filesystem problem first,
Also check the available disk space on this directory, may be there is no space.

Comment: I tried that and i get no error but still mysql dont start

Answer (score -1):

Change directory permission to read, write and execute..

Chmod 777 /directory_path