# Unable to install mysql server on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-12.04, uninstallation

I have been unsuccessful at installing a mysql server on Ubuntu 12.04.  Here is what I see when I try to install after a remove --purge of mysql server:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/8,861 kB of archives.
After this operation, 32.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 257077 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 
    (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
150705 15:38:03 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of 
    key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
    Please use the full name instead.
150705 15:38:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) 
    starting as process 14658 ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup 
    error from a previous failure.
            dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A mysql client is installed, but when I try to launch it I get this:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292865/upgrade-mysql-server-issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got no help from StackExchange, so I dug deeper and figured it out myself:  First I got rid of mysql-server and mysql-client by following instructions at [Removing MySQL 5.5 Completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely).  Then I simply installed the server and client as usual with apt-get.  Everything worked fine after that.