# Can't Install Mysql 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to upgrade from Mysql 5.5 to Mysql 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

I've tried:

- Installing directly with **sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6** - no success
- Removing Mysql 5.5 fully first, according to this thread: [Removing MySQL 5.5 Completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely) then installing with sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 - no success
- Creating 4g swap like explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457923/why-did-installation-of-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-04-fail - no success

None of these options worked.. the error I get is this:

```
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.19 started; log sequence number 1626183
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] Binlog end
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-07-06 02:32:33 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-07-06 02:32:35 12412 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626193
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-common-5.6 (5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
```

I can't set it up, getting really really frustrated

Running on Digital Ocean VPS, please enlighten me masters :(

Comment: Can you provide error logs (i.e. from  /var/log/mysql/error.log) ?

Comment: the log file shows the same message as above (shutdown completed ....)

Answer (score 0):

It seems "innodb_buffer_pool_size" variable size is set too low in your configuration file, so increase it as per your server RAM (you can set upto 80% of total RAM) and then try...

Comment: where should I set that? I didn't find it in the default my.cnf

Comment: update innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G (as per your RAM), in my.cnf under [mysqld] section

Comment: tried it, and it didn't work.. then I upgrade my server from 512 to 1gb ram, and it worked.. I wonder why it didn't work with 4gb swap memory though, any ideas?

Comment: bcoz mysql 5.6 need  more than 128MB (which is default ram set) for innodb_buffer_pool initialization, so you need at least 1 GB RAM to start mysql 5.6. Regarding swap it is not RAM it is part of ROM, but yes system will consider it as RAM in some manner as your RAM will be utilized completely...

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem before, in my situation, it happens because i use vagrant vpc server.

```
1.remove all Local MySQL
$ sudo apt-get autoremove –purge mysql*
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/

2.install mysql
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get build-dep mysql-server-5.6
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

If you still have problem, check the following info:

1. Increase the amount of memory in your EC2
2. Set a smaller value for MySQL’s max_connections variable