# Ubuntu: I can't run mysql properly or even reinstall it

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I tried to use mysql but i found that it was broken so i tried to remove it by using the apt-get remove mysql* and it output a message to me: Try using apt-get -f install i tried it and i got this error:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This seem to be relatively common and I don't think it has anything to do with MySQL, but rather Apt-Get or dpkg: Check out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642173 Also, this is off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
 sudo service mysql stop  #or mysqld
 sudo killall -9 mysql
 sudo killall -9 mysqld
 sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
 sudo apt-get autoremove
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo deluser mysql
 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
 sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5
 sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5
 sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
 sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

[Removing MySQL 5.5 Completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely/16178696#16178696)

And then reinstall

EDIT:

This page also seems to deal with issues similar: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1229506

Comment: I can't i get the same errors.

Comment: list what you have installed and post it here. list with this command:
dpkg -l mysql