# Facing issue while installing PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install PHPMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 16 setup.
I am using this document to do so:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04

But I am getting following error while installation:
[image]

I even try to uninstall mysql completely for which I used following steps, but it did not work.

[Removing MySQL 5.5 Completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely/16178696#16178696)

Comment: *empty value for "port" specified* - have you entered a port number?

Comment: no, I have not entered any port number

Answer (score 0):

First of all You have to remove whole phpmyadmin from your system using

1. sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin mysql-server mysql-client
2. sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin mysql-server
3. sudo apt-get autoremove
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
6. sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server

Comment: Installing phpmyadmin before mysql? No, it does not work like that...