# Wampserver login failure mysql windows 7

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

When I try to log into phpmyadmin from wamp server(2.4 windows 7), following error comes up

## 2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I used "root" as the username and empty box(didn't type anything) as the password

Wamp server was working fine until yesterday. Now the icon on the system tray is orange in color( earlier it was green)

Any body who can help??

Comment: check if it is online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting all the services by left-click on wamp icon.

Or try the solutions on 
[phpMyAdmin is throwing a #2002 cannot log in to the mysql server phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)

Also read this post,
 http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119961

Comment: About the old Q & A s My server was working perfectly. Its giving this error only since yesterday

Comment: did you recently install skype?

Comment: No I did not install anything recently

Comment: try the solution on  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119961. Or back up your www folder and reinstall wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute `netstat -nlpt` command.And figure out mysql process .Kill it and start your wampp.

Comment: how do I do that. When I execute that command it lists several letters and a description. How do I find the mysql process?

Comment: find out mysql port and check process id

Comment: pass me the output of that

Answer (score 0):

If you change your mysql port, so you need to check mysql port on php.ini

```
mysqli.default_port = <your_port_goes_here>
```

Default port is 3306. So if you change your port, you need to change your port on php.ini and restart all services. In some case, this small mistake produce error `#2002  Cannot log in to the MySQL server`.