# #2002 cannot log in to the MySql server-only from specific computer

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-2002

I have a DB hosted on a server, log in with phpMyAdmin.

I can connect to it perfectly, without any problem.

But the problem is that my friend can't connect to it, and he gets the error below.

> 2002 cannot log in to the MySql server

I asked from different friends of mine to connect (gave them the user and password of course) and all of them can also connect successfully.

Also I asked from a friend that doesn't understand in computers at all (what show that the problem is not depend on installing a specific software. he has "clean" windows), and he can also connect.

I think the problem is not with my configurations (I am the admin) because everybody can connect, except my specific friend!

My friend (with the problem) tried to disable firewall and antivirus(avg), and it didn't fix the problem. He has windows 7.

What else can we try?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)

Comment: If you means to try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php, i don't know where is this file. Actually, any of my friends didn't install phpMyAdmin or any other software...

Comment: Try the options given in this [url](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/access-denied.html)

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, you have installed phpMyAdmin to your hosted server and every one of you is accessing that same phpMyAdmin account, right? None of you have installed phpMyAdmin directly to your machines?

Comment: closed post- the problem was foolishly typing the password incorrectly.