# Starting MySQL database server mysqld [fail]

Tags: mysql, failed-installation

When I start MySql it just failed why?

> mypc@computer:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
>
> - Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                [ OK ]
> - Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [fail]

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: When I write this command (sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart) and press enter button it will return * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld [OK] * Starting MySQL database server mysqld [fail] nothing else

Comment: try `sudo vim /var/log/mysql.err`

Comment: sudo: vim: command not found

Comment: Okay, then try `sudo gedit /var/log/mysql.err`

Comment: And it will also return error on my magento home page SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: I just install the WordPress in my system and after that when I login MySql it will return (#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server) this message

Comment: nothing it will display

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)

> If you're getting the #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server error while logging in to phpmyadmin, try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and change:
>
> `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`
>
> to:
>
> `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`