# Xampp phpMyAdmin Access Denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using windows 10. I recently installed Xampp into my laptop, changed the port number for Apache and MySql. They are all starting fine but when i go to phpMyAdmin i get this error message [access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlzCv.png)

[Here are MySql logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My0co.png)

Kindly assist me on this matter

Comment: When you changed the MySQL listen port, did you also change the port in the phpMyAdmin configuration file to match?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server error while logging in to phpmyadmin, try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and change:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';

to:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Solution from Ryan's blog

referr below

[phpMyAdmin is throwing a #2002 cannot log in to the mysql server phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

check if you are using skype login and uncheck port no 80 and login in again in skype 
    check this link for instructions http://el.web.id/how-to-solve-xampp-problem-port-80-443-in-use-by-skype-470

Answer (score 0):

This issue mostly appears when one tries to set or change mysql password.
Try editing phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and config.sample.inc.php files.