# phpmyadmin - error 2002 - on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I'm currently using Mac, and the running OS version is El Capitan. The web root is `/Users/username/Sites`.

I downloaded, extracted the phpmyadmin and moved the directory to the root folder, and I managed to get to the log in screen. But when I try to log in, it shows a message like this.

```
#2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I checked out if MySQL was turned off, but it was on so it doesn't have to do with that. Does anybody know how to solve out this matter?

Comment: Are you using Apache as web server?

Comment: @RandallValenciano Yes.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the log?

Comment: @RandallValenciano Sorry but which log?

Comment: @RandallValenciano The error message above is directly from the phpmyadmin screen on the browser. I'm not using any tools now.

Comment: Apache has an error log, located: /var/log/apache2/error_log where are more details of your error. Anyway, did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @RandallValenciano Actually I did, and there I found something very weird again. One of the solutions suggested there was to modify a line of code in `config.inc.php` file, but there is no file named so in the phpmyadmin directory. The only one that had the closest name to it was `config.sample.inc.php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101110/discussion-between-randall-valenciano-and-newbieprogrammer).

Comment: Issue solved. Please post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 24):

So the solution was fairly simple for my case.

After reading some articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin), I viewed my phpmyadmin directory to find the `config.inc.php` file. This is what I still haven't figured out but there was no file with the same name.

Instead, the file with the closest name was `config.sample.inc.php`, so I changed its file name and changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`. Now I can log in with the phpmyadmin account.

Comment: Thank you!  This solved it.  Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same error after upgrading mariadb through `homebrew upgrade` on OS X Siera 10.12.5.

Turns out that a config directory was missing:

```
mysql: Can't read dir of '/usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

Simply creating this directory solves the issue (no need to restart the mariadb daemon):

```
mkdir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d
```

Wait a few seconds and retry to connect:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 9
Server version: 10.2.6-MariaDB Homebrew
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

1. brew services mysql stop
2. Go to Xampp and restart mysql service.