# MacOS MAMP and php 8.1

Tags: macos, mamp

I am trying to get MAMP runing with PHP 8.1 but what I see as latest version for MacOS is 8.0.8, is there a way to run 8.1 ?

I have gone thru many tutorials in which they explain on how to switch from one of the installed versions but I can't seem to find a way to install additional PHP versions.

Comment: I also would like to know... Usually you just have to download a php version and add it to the bin/php folder

Answer (score 15):

following up relating to @Quink's answer

[image: add additional php versions]

8.1.0 is available in the dropdown (not in the picture because I already downloaded it)

then quit and restart mamp
[image: select 8.1.0]

then you can find the folder by opening phpinfo page and seeing the path
[image]

not sure if this is needed, but at this point I copied the folder and pasted it in the main MAMP/conf directory where all the other PHP versions are

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for this myself. I found out that the easiest way to do this is to start your trial version of the pro. There you have the option to download/ install the php8.1 version. After this I switched back to the basic MAMP and everything is working properly

Answer (score 4):

Install homebrew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

get latest php version i.e. 8.1 for now

```
brew install php
```

Verify php

```
which php
php -version
```

now go to to /usr/loca/Cellar/php, copy php version folder you want i.e. 8.1 for now
go to Application/MAMP/bin/php and paste this folder

rename your folder like others i.e. "8.1.10_1" to  "php8.1.10" in my case

at this point you can quite the mamp and reopen it and you will see php8.1 version in your mamp php version's dropdown

now go to your terminal and

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start
```

and you will see an error i.e. Syntax error on line 160 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf... in my case

to resolve this go to /usr/local/lib/httpd/ and copy the "modules" folder

now past it in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.1.10/

YOUR MAMP IS ALL SET BUT if you try to reach phpadmin you will see an error, for that

go to /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin5 and edit config.inc.php.

Locate this text: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'` and change it to ``$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'`

Restart your server.

HOPE THIS HELP YOU

Comment: I have MAMP but I can't see the version installed. When I type `which php` in the terminal, it says No `php not found`. Maybe because it was installed through a third party application like MAMP?

Comment: Yes, it is not available on your terminal then

Answer (score 2):

This [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8KRaPnz1e8) answers this perfectly, and then follow this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797848/9259701)

You might also want to change your local connection host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

PS: Copy `/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.<version_number>/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so` to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.<version_number>/modules/libphp.so`

Comment: Thank you for this sir; perfectly worked! But indeed only after changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.01`; do you actually know why??

Comment: I don't sadly :), I haven't had the time to investigate. @DevelJoe

Comment: Typo, I obviously meant 127.0.0.1. Hmm I guess this can only be due to some cache like stuff of established connections, can't think of anything else