# Failed to load phpMyAdmin configuration (./config.inc.php:31): parse error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-elcapitan

hello guys i made a fresh install of phpmyadmin in my computer. after making a new host i tried to log in but phpmyadmin throwing

> #2002 - No such file or directory
> The server is not responding
>   (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)

.

i searched for this error and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694575/phpmyadmin-is-throwing-a-2002-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin) example i made the proper changes, first of all, the name of the file from   *config.sample.inc.php* to *config.inc.php* and after that i changed the line of the document as the example suggests. Then when i am trying to redirect in phpmyadmin it triggers this error

> Failed to load phpMyAdmin configuration (./config.inc.php:31): parse
>   error

this error is triggering only when i change the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

my operating system is OS X el capitan 10.11.6

any ideas will be helpfull

thanks in advance

vaggelis

Comment: Can you connect to your mysql server? When you log in, do you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? What does it show for your host? `show processlist;` will show what host you're connected from.

Comment: @aynber That would lead to a connection error at run time, not to a parse error.

Comment: @arkascha Good point. I was focusing too much on the beginning of the issue before the OP changed their config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it guys, i havent started my database after installed mysql. it was that silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is **silly mistake** in any file, like : (C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin/config.inc)

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio  Silly mistake like : forget the semi-column,  by mistake type the any character or word in the script file and some script data are case-sensitive. **script file is don't understand your character or word.** That's why this type of error generate.